# Notebook epigram referring to 'only death in the universe'

Tags: french-language, quote-source, albert-camus

Camus says somewhere that there is only death in the universe. By 'death' he simply means physics (energy, matter). He is rejecting the metaphysics of a universal dualism: Life and Death. I believe this is an epigram from one of his notebooks, but in any case I would appreciate being reminded of where he wrote this.